# How to execute job:dispatch during phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Inside my `phpunit.xml` I have set the `QUEUE_DRIVER` to null:

```
<env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="null"/>
```

Unfortunately, job dispatches are not executed.

For Example, I have this dummy test:

```
public function test_dummy()
{
    \App\Jobs\DummyJob::dispatch();
    dd('DummyJob is not executed');
}
```

and thats the job:

```
public function handle()
{
    dd('alright');
}
```

phpunit returns

> DummyJob is not executed

Is it possible to change `phpunit.xml` so that job-patches are executed immediately, just like it works with queued mails?

Comment: My guess is that, since [`NullDriver` has a fixed size of `0`](https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/master/NullQueue.php#L15), dispatch sees no work to do. You'll likely need to do something like `ArrayDriver extends NullDriver` and push at least one dummy placeholder in.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `QUEUE_DRIVER` from `null` to `sync`.

Setting `QUEUE_DRIVER` to `null` will discard any queued jobs.

Setting QUEUE_DRIVER`to`sync` will run queued jobs immediatly and is thus recommend for testing purposes, but not for production.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way of testing Queue functionality works during testing is to use the inbuilt mock functionality. Queues act different from sync to async setups (setting a property on a model reference will be there in sync not in async or similar). Assert that the job is called with correct properties.

```
    Queue::fake();

    $answer = 42;

    Queue::assertPushed(YourJob::class, function ($job) use ($answer) {
        return $job->answer=== $answer;
    });
```

This does not test that it actually works, instead you should test the job separately like so.

```
(new YourJob($answer))->handle();

$this->assertDatabaseHas('your_awesome_table', ['column' => 'value']);
```